# smooth Luzin theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory

For measurable functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$ on $[0,1]$ define the distance $\rho(f,g)$ as a Lebesgue measure of the set $\{x:f(x)\ne g(x)\}$. Then Luzin's famous theorem states that $C[0,1]$ is dense with respect to this metric in the set of all measurable functions.

The question is to describe the completion of $C^1[0,1]$ (that is, informally, for given function give a receipt how to recognize wether it belongs to completion or not.)

Comment: Related:  http://mathoverflow.net/q/34518/5701 and the answer which shows that whatever the completion is, it is not all of $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Any such function must have an "$L^0$ derivative", in the sense that $\frac{1}{t}(f(\cdot + t) - f(\cdot))$ has a limit in measure as $t \to 0$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This holds precisely if $f$ is approximately differentiable a.e. This condition implies that $f|_A$ can be extended to a $C^1$ function for suitable sets $A$ of almost full measure by a Theorem from Federer's book, or see [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=EzkG1lf2G8kC&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=approximately%20differentiable%20federer%27s%20theorem&source=bl&ots=UVv6s75W9B&sig=8nB2Y7Rio2XBJPuurVaC_EDyB84&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FH5pU_OFMoaBogTh_IKYBQ&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=approximately%20differentiable%20federer%27s%20theorem&f=false).

The converse is obvious: If $f=g\in C^1$ on $A$, then $f$ is approximately differentiable at all points of density of $A$.

Comment: This result is due to  Whitney, see https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=43878&loc=fromreflist