# Exchanging series and integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, limits-and-convergence, lebesgue-measure, divergent-series

I know that I can use Lebesgue or monotone convergence theorem to exchange limit of partial sums and a Lebesgue integral, given a power series or a generic function series. But in general given a series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ which converges, and defined $\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n f_n(u)du$ with $f_n(u)$ integrable, I was wondering when I could exchange the integration and the series. In particular in the context of Borel summation , given $\int_0^\infty e^{-u} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_nu^n}{n!}du$, I was wondering how could I demonstrate that if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then I can exchange the integral and the series. (I know that for power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n z^n$ the work can be done using the radius of convergence and I can always find a dominant)

Comment: A very general [necessary and sufficient condition for the passage to the limit under the integral sign is known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296312/do-you-know-important-theorems-that-remain-unknown/296839#296839): it is not so easy to use, but you can try and see if it can be useful for your problem.

Comment: First thing I would try is Fubini.  This works for $$\int_0^\infty e^{-u} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_nu^n}{n!}du$$ provided $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Gerald Edgar, we can use the Fubini--Tonelli theorem. By the Tonelli theorem,
$$\int_0^\infty \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Big|e^{-u} \frac{a_nu^n}{n!}\Big|\,du
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{n!}\int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^n\,du
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|<\infty.$$
So, the Fubini theorem is applicable, that is, one can interchange the integral and the series.

Comment: Being pedantic technically we should write the series as an integral over an appropriate measure and moreover we should demonstrate that 
$$\int_0^\infty  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Big| e^{-u}\frac{a_nu^n}{n!}\Big|\,du
< \infty.$$ and because of integrability, we can swap the oringinal integral and sum. Now here $\int_0^\infty e^{-u} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{|a_n|u^n}{n!}\,du
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{n!}\int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^n\,du$ are we using Tonelli's Thm. for non-negative measurable functions?
But if the series is uniformly convergent can we use the Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Comment: @Coltrane8 : (i) Of course, the sum is the integral over the counting measure. (ii) I have now taken into account your point about the use of the Fubini theorem. (iii) I don't see a way to use dominated convergence.