# Dominated convergence theorem when the measure space also varies with $n$

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory, sequences-and-series

Let $(f_n)_n:X \to \mathbb R$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a measurable space $X$ converging pointwise to a function $f:X \to \mathbb R$, and let $(\mu_n)_n$ be a sequence of finite measures (e.g probability measures) on $X$ such that each $f_n$ is integrable w.r.t $\mu_n$.

> **Question.** *Under what additional conditions do we have $\int_X (f_n-f)\,d\mu_n \to 0$ ?*

**Note.** In case it helps, it may be assumed that $\mu_n$ converges (in some sense) to a measure $\mu$ on $X$.

Comment: For every countable family $\mu_n$ of finite measures you find another one $\lambda$ which dominates them all in the sense that $\lambda(A)=0$ implies $\mu_n(A)=0$. Radon-Nikodym implies that $\mu_n$ have densities $\varphi_n$ so that you ask for $\int f_n\varphi_nd\lambda \to \int f\varphi d\lambda$.

Comment: Without Radon-Nikodym: For non-negative $f$, $\lim\int_X f_n-fd\mu_n=\lim\int_0^\infty \mu_n \left (\{x \in X \mid f_n(x)-f(x)>t\} \right )dt$.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the input. @JochenWengenroth, so, one deduces that if $\mu_n = \varphi_n d\lambda$ and $\varphi_n \to \varphi$ pointwise, and $f_n$ is dominated by some $\lambda$-integrable function, then $\int_X|f_n-f|d\mu_n \to 0$ by the classical *Dominated Convergence Theorem*, right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$The conjunction of the following conditions is enough:

1. The $f_n$'s are uniformly bounded: $|f_n|\le M$ for some real $M>0$ and all $n$;
2. $X$ is Polish;
3. $f_n\to f$ uniformly on every compact $K\subseteq X$;
4. $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly for some $\mu$.

Indeed, take any real $\ep>0$. By [Prokhorov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20measure%20theory%20Prokhorov%27s%20theorem,on%20complete%20separable%20metric%20spaces.) and in view of conditions 2 and 4, $\mu_n(X\setminus K)<\ep$ for some compact $K\subseteq X$ and all $n$. Write
$$I_n:=\int_X(f_n-f)\,d\mu_n=I_{1,n}+I_{2,n},$$
where
$$I_{1,n}:=\int_K(f_n-f)\,d\mu_n,\quad
I_{2,n}:=\int_{X\setminus K}(f_n-f)\,d\mu_n.$$
By condition 3, $I_{1,n}\to0$. By conditions 1 and 3, $|f|\le M$ and hence $|f_n-f|\le2M$. So, $|I_{2,n}|\le2M\ep$. So, $\limsup_n|I_n|\le2M\ep$, for every real $\ep>0$.  So, $I_n\to0$, as desired.

Answer (score 5):

This answer should perhaps be posted as a comment, since the whole topic was already debated in this [MathOverflow Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296312/do-you-know-important-theorems-that-remain-unknown/296839#296839). However i briefly restate the main result here and leave the above link for further detals: a definitive answer is Cafiero's convergence theorem (see [1]) which, roughly states that$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dm}{\operatorname{d\!}}$
$$
\int_X f_n\Dm\mu_n - \int_X f\Dm\mu_n \to 0 \iff \text{$(f_n\cdot\mu_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is uniformly exaustive.}
$$
Note that this *necessary and sufficient condition* is not very well known, even in the circles of measure theorists.

**Reference**

[1] Cafiero, F. (1953), "[Sul passaggio al limite sotto il segno d'integrale per successioni d'integrali di Stieltjes-Lebesgue negli spazi astratti, con masse variabili con gli integrandi](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=RSMUP_1953__22__223_0)" [On the passage to the limit under the sign of integral for sequences of Stieltjes–Lebesgue integrals in abstract spaces, with masses varying jointly with integrands], Rendiconti del Seminario Matematico della Università di Padova (in Italian), 22: 223–245, [MR0057951](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0057951), [Zbl 0052.05003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0052.05003).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Cafiero's theorem (new to me).  Upvoted.The notion of *exhaustiveness* eludes me. Are there any conditions which can be imposed separately on $(f_n)_n$ and $(\mu_n)_n)$ (in the spirit of those mentioned in the question), to ensure that $(f_n\mu_n)_n$ is "uniformly exhaustive" ?

Comment: @dohmatob to my knowledge, no: however, as said in the linked Q&A, Gaetano Fichera  proved a simpler necessary and sufficient condition for the case $\mu_n=\mu$ for all $n$. Perhaps you can have a look at this fact in order to find conditions on $\{f_n\}$ and $\{\mu_n\}$ to assure that the family of their product $\{f_n\mu_n\}$ is uniformly exaustive.

Comment: When $\mu_n = \mu$ for all $n$, then we are back to the classical DCT (and avatars). The last part of your remark is precisely the question in my last comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using the Radon-Nikodym Theorem this problem can be reduced to the case for a fixed measure.

Suppose none of the $\mu_n$ is the zero-measure, i.e. $\mu_n(X)>0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

For a series $(\alpha_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset (0,1)$ with $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n = 1$ define the probability measure
$$
\mu = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n \, \frac{\mu_n}{\mu_n(X)} \ .
$$
Now for any set $A \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ we have the implication
$$
0= \mu(A) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n \, \frac{\mu_n(A)}{\mu_n(X)} \ \Rightarrow \ 0 = \mu_n
$$
for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Radon-Nikodym then implies the existance of measurable functions $g_n : X \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that $\mu_n = g_n \cdot \mu$ or equvalently
$$
\mu_n(A) = \int_A g_n \, d\mu \ , \ \forall A \in \mathcal{B}(X) \ .
$$
The question whether $\int_X f_n-f \, d\mu_n$ converges to zero now becomes the question whether $\int_X (f_n-f)g_n \, d\mu$ converges to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The question to which you've reduced the situation doesn't seem very transparent / exploitable (due to the construction of $\mu$).